# CSS: Static Background Image to cover any screen size but not exceed image size

Tags: css

I want to create a perfect full background image that is static and that fills the viewport, no matter what the size of the screen(viewport) is.

So I use the following CSS:

```
body, html{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: url('http://ns223506.ovh.net/rozne/d4857d4e0f68027e7af6b70d5488b7e6/wallpaper-751328.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
           background-size: cover;
}
```

Now the problem is...As far as I understand, when the viewport size exceeds the size of the image, the image will stretch and will pixelate...

How can I prevent the max size being passed?

Also, what is the best way to approach this screen size problem when you want to cater for retina display resolutions? Set a max-width on the body, html elements?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@media` queries to decide till what resolution you want the image to cover the entire page, if the resolution gets bigger, either replace it with another image, or simply use `center` value for `background position` and a `background color`, if you are not looking to cover the image after certain resolution, this will prevent the image to get pixelat.. For example

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7FGm/) (Resize the fiddle window for desired effect)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image: url('https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/p480x480/1231_381212385330183_1145397211_n.jpg');  
    /* If it exceeds 699px width, you can also replace the image here... */
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
           background-size: cover;
}

@media all and (max-width: 699px) {
  body {
        background-color: #000;
        background-image: url('https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/p480x480/1231_381212385330183_1145397211_n.jpg');
        background-size: 200px 200px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
}
```

> Note: I've used `@media all and (max-width: 699px)` and `background-size: 200px 200px` here in this example
>   just for demonstration purposes, you can replace this with original
>   height/width of your image and the desired resolution for `@media` rule

Comment: Cool, thank you. I was kinda thinking in the same direction...just wasn't sure if there is maybe another way of doing it.